# Run cURL/Batch on my Android device

Tags: android, python, bash, curl

I have developed a shell script to reconnect my Router.
It works fine with Curl ([Die curl-7.38.0-win64.msi](http://www.confusedbycode.com/curl/)) and `sh.exe` from GIT for Windows. 
It works fine on my PC.

Now I want to find a way to run the following Script on my Android Device.
I have successfully installed Curl on it but can't run it; it shows the following error:

> "error: only position independent executables (PIE) are supported."

It has to do with Lollipop restrictions. Is it possible to do this on other way like Tasker, Restfull, or Pythons Mechanize?

```
#!/bin/sh
strindex() { 
  x="${1%%$2*}"
  [[ $x = $1 ]] && echo -1 || echo ${#x}
}

curl 'http://easy.box/cgi-bin/login.exe' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.5,en;q=0.3' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Host: easy.box' -H 'Referer: http://easy.box/' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -c cookies.txt --data 'pws=DEIN_PASSWORT' --location
sleep 6 
reply=$(curl -b cookies.txt 'http://easy.box/cgi-bin/status_restart.exe' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Host: easy.box' -H 'Referer: http://easy.box/main_status-and-support.stm#sub=restart' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0' --location)
sleep 6 
echo $reply
sleep 1 
#curl 'http://easy.box/login.stm'


index=$(strindex "$reply" "var _httoken")
echo $index

# we grab the first 40 letters...
tokenString=${reply:$index:40}
echo "Found TokenLine:$tokenString"

#strip start of string
tokenStringEnd=${tokenString##*= }
#strip end of string
token=${tokenStringEnd%%;*}
echo "Extracted token:$token"

echo "Sending reconnect command..."
curl -b cookies.txt 'http://easy.box/cgi-bin/status_restart.exe' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Host: easy.box' -H 'Referer: http://easy.box/main_status-and-support.stm#sub=restart' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0' --location --data "httoken=$token"
```

Thanks for answers, ideas and solutions!

Comment: Did you get curl for android from http://curl.haxx.se/gknw.net/7.40.0/dist-android/curl-7.40.0-rtmp-ssh2-ssl-zlib-static-bin-android.tar.gz  or from somewhere else?

Comment: no from the Play Store as App. These App install cURL. On Android 4.4 it works fine. How To install  curl.haxx.se/gknw.net/7.40.0/dist-android/… version?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed it! Since the Android "L" Google still have PIE check enabled. If you have the same problem you have to flash this [bypass-pie.zip](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2821644&d=1403933203) which overwrites one byte in /system/bin/linker to bypass the PIE check!
[More infos here!!!](http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/development/fix-bypassing-pie-security-check-t2797731)